Even Fibonacci sequence numbers
I was looking at the Fibonacci sequence and I noticed that you can use the formula
$4(n) + n[i-3]$ (where $n$ is some even Fibonacci number, and $n[i-3]$ is really just the last even number)
ie. $4(2) + 0 = 8 , 4(8) + 2 = 34 , 4(34) + 8 = 144$
To find the next even number in the sequence. I am just wondering why it is that you can find even Fibonacci sequence numbers using this, why does this happen? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new. Thanks

This question is similar to: Proving that if $E_n$ is an even number of the Fibonacci sequence, then the next even number is $E_{n+1} = 4E_{n} + E_{n-1}$. I'm moving my answer there to avoid duplicating posts.
